# chrome://inspect/#devices not working in Huawei LLD-L31

Tags: google-chrome

I'm trying to remote debug chrome javascript on Huawei LLD-L31 device: I can't find any way to see my device in chrome://inspect/#devices

I'm on xubuntu linux 22.04

```
$ apt show adb
Package: adb
Version: 1:10.0.0+r36-9
Priority: optional
Section: universe/devel
Source: android-platform-system-core
Origin: Ubuntu
Maintainer: Ubuntu Developers <ubuntu-devel-discuss@lists.ubuntu.com>
Original-Maintainer: Android Tools Maintainers <android-tools-devel@lists.alioth.debian.org>
Bugs: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+filebug
Installed-Size: 263 kB
Provides: android-tools-adb
Depends: android-libadb (= 1:10.0.0+r36-9), android-sdk-platform-tools-common (>= 28.0.2~), android-libbase (>= 1:10.0.0+r36), libc6 (>= 2.34), libgcc-s1 (>= 3.0), libstdc++6 (>= 9)
Breaks: android-tools-adb (<< 6.0~)
Replaces: android-tools-adb (<< 6.0~)
Homepage: https://android.googlesource.com/platform/system/core
Download-Size: 98,7 kB
APT-Manual-Installed: yes
APT-Sources: http://cu.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy/universe amd64 Packages
Description: Android Debug Bridge
 Strumento versatile a riga di comando che permette di comunicare con
 un'istanza di emulatore o con un dispositivo Android connesso.
 .
 Questo pacchetto raccomanda "android-sdk-platform-tools-common" che
 contiene le regole udev per i dispositivi Android. Senza questo pacchetto,
 adb e fastboot devono essere eseguiti con permessi di root.
```

Any hint?